# Opening a HTTP session with a username and password

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I am trying to open a HTTP session with a username and password using AFNetworking.

The code I have at the moment is:

```
NSURL* serverURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://myurl.com"];
AFHTTPClient* network = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL: serverURL];
[networkInstance setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"myUsername" 
                                           password:@"myPassword"];
```

Is this all there is to it? I've looked around a bit and I can't seem to find any examples of a connection that uses a username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation:

> This block sets the `Authorization` HTTP header set in request objects
>   made by the HTTP client to a basic authentication value with
>   Base64-encoded username and password.

So, if the server you're using uses basic authentication, yes, that's all there is to it.

Some other servers authenticate differently, such as with a token or certificate.  For most uses, though, this is all you have to do.